# Running code at memory location in my OS

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I am developing an OS in C (and some assembly of course) and now I want to allow it to load/run external (placed in the RAM-disk) programs. I have assembled a test program as raw machine code with nasm using '-f bin'. Everything else i found on the subject is loading code while running Windows or Linux. I load the program into memory using the following code:

```
#define BIN_ADDR 0xFF000
int run_bin(char *file) //Too many hacks at the moment
{
    u32int size = 0;
    char *bin = open_file(file, &size);
    printf("Loaded [%d] bytes of [%s] into [%X]\n", size, file, bin);
    char *reloc = (char *)BIN_ADDR; //no malloc because of the org statement in the prog
    memset(reloc, 0, size);
    memcpy(reloc, bin, size);
    jmp_to_bin();
}
```

and the code to jump to it:

```
[global jmp_to_bin]
jmp_to_bin:
    jmp [bin_loc] ;also tried a plain jump

bin_loc dd 0xFF000
```

This caused a GPF when I ran it. I could give you the registers at the GPF and/or a screenshot if needed.

Code for my OS is at https://github.com/farlepet/retro-os

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this 16-bit code? Your use of `far` indicates that it might be. If that's the case, then the address `FF000` is not valid in 16-bit land.

Comment: If this is real code, then the variable `bin` is never initialized. Thus, `memcpy` most likely just copies garbage.

Comment: Oh, far can only be used in 16 bit code? this is 32 bit, so `0xFF000` is valid. But I did try it without `far` and it still issued a GPF.

Comment: Codo: bin is initilized in the function open_file, it is malloc'd then the file is copied to it

Comment: The function `open_file()` cannot change the value of `bin` in the calling function (since the pointer is passed by value). This is almost definitely one of the problems here.

Comment: Greg: I cant beleive i didnt think about that... Well, ill change my code and see if that does anything. (It WAS saying that bin pointed to 2, but  thought it was a but in my printf)

Comment: *updated but still creates a GPF

Comment: A popular tutorial I found on OSDev.org suggests, if I remember correctly, that the default placement of string constants used by most toolchains is erroneous and it makes the CPU try to execute the string literal itself. What if you get rid of the `printf()` call?

Comment: Surely dd 0xff000 - maybe you want to do a near jmp, given that it's a 32-bit system? Loading cs with whatever is after 0xff000 would do a GPF, pretty certainly [unless it just so HAPPENS to match a valid CS entry in the GDT]

Comment: @H2CO3: I tried removing the printf statements, but it still issues a GPF, and could you provide a link to that tutorial?
@MatsPetersson: Tried it both ways, and got the same result with `jmp` as `jmp far`

Comment: The core.img in your git repo is empty, I assume that should contain the binary you are trying to load? Can you update it? Also, use a debugger to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @farlepet Sorry, not off the top of my head, but I remember having come there from osdev.org.

Comment: @Jester: I use an ISO, and it is not in the git directory, ill fix that right now, and the binary too...

Comment: @Jester: I updated the git repo with the ISO [Retro.iso] and executable [in the bin_progs directory]

Comment: The jump is all right, but the code is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use identity mapping and flat memory space, hence address 0xff000 is gonna be in the BIOS ROM range. No wonder you can't copy stuff there. Better change that address ;)

[image: bochs screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, ill try that when I get time. I forgot to look at http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86). And I see that text on the screen, did you get it working at `0x8000`?

Comment: Yes, I used 0x8000 for this test.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now! One more thing, can I use call instead of jmp, and use a ret in the bin?

Comment: For the time being, yes. In the future you will probably want an `exit` system call.

Comment: What do you mean by an exit system call, you mean telling the system to stop program execution istead of doing it manually? Doing a call and ret causes a Page Fault during/after the ret...

Comment: Note that `jmp_to_bin` is already `call`-ed from C, so there you can keep the `jmp` so the `ret` that presumably comes at the end of the binary will return back to the C caller. You'll have a problem with call and ret when you get user and kernel mode, though, that's where a syscall will be better.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Jester, eventually I will see if I can get this working with loading ELF executables and multitasking.